# How to Select a record from the database and update it in an atomic query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, select, atomic

I have a number of records in a table with a Status column and I want to select a single record where Status = Pending and in the same atomic query mark it as Status = InProcess.  What's the best way to do that?

This is needed because multiple queries can be running at the same time trying to process these records and I don't want two threads to be picking up the same record to process.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use OUTPUT clause:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET Status = 'InProcess'
OUTPUT deleted.*
WHERE Status = 'Pending'
```

Here you can use **inserted** table name if you want to get row with new status or **deleted** when old.

Comment: +1. Learned something new today :). This will return the record just before updating it

Comment: Thanks a lot.  this is awesome.  Exactly what I was looking for.  BTW if anyone is interested this works in SQL2005 and up.

Comment: This doesn't just do a single record though as specified in the question.

Comment: @Martin: I modified the first row to achieve that: UPDATE TOP (1) [table]

Answer (score 8):

Here is an article about [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

With this table `create table T (ID int identity, Status varchar(15))`
 Something like this should keep you safe from deadlocks.

```
;with cte as
(
  select top 1 *
  from T with (rowlock, readpast)
  where Status = 'Pending'
  order by ID
)
update cte
set Status = 'InProcess'
output inserted.ID, inserted.Status
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick

```
UPDATE [table]
SET Status = 'InProcess'
WHERE Status = 'Pending'
```

SQL 2008 should take care of any locking for you.

Comment: I also need to select that record.

Comment: So what needs to happen first? Do you want to select it first and then update, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

This following is kind of a hack, but it worked for me for atomic read/updates:

```
declare temp1, temp2, ...;
update table
   set temp1=column1,
       temp2=column2, ... 
       column1=expression1,
       column2=expression2, ...
where conditions;
select temp1, temp2, ...;
```